# nginx AD authentication failure

Tags: nginx, active-directory, ldap

Tried to configure Nginx to authenticate using AD and have been getting the following error.

```
2018/03/22 17:07:51 [error] 6981#0: http_auth_ldap: Could not connect
```

Have tried different ways of writing the ldap url, but none of them seems to work. The current authentication module in the configuration(nginx.conf) file looks like this:

```
ldap_server auth_server{
    url ldap://corp.xxxxxx.co.xx:389/dc=corp,dc=xxxxxx,dc=co,dc=xx?uid?sub?(&(objectClass=person));
    binddn "CORP\\desktop_user_xxxxx";
    binddn_passwd "Pxxxxxxxx";
    group_attribute uniquemember;
    group_attribute_is_dn on;
    require valid_user;
}
```

I have also tried the following:

```
ldap_server auth_server{
    url ldap://corp.xxxxxx.co.xx:389/dc=corp,dc=xxxxxx,dc=co,dc=xx?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=person);
    binddn "CORP\\desktop_user_xxxxx";
    binddn_passwd "Pxxxxxxxx";
    group_attribute uniquemember;
    group_attribute_is_dn on;
    require valid_user;
}
```

ldapsearch with the same credentials however, works, indicating that the credentials are correct and the server is reachable.

```
ldapsearch  -b "dc=corp,dc=xxxxxx,dc=co,dc=xx" -D "CORP\\desktop_user_xxxxx" -H "ldap://corp.xxxxxx.co.xx" -w Pxxxxxxxx  "(&(objectClass=Person)(sAMAccountName=xxxx))"
```

How can I convert this ldapsearch string to the URL in the ldap_server in nginx.conf?

Answer (score 0):

The `binddn` in the nginx config needs to be an actual distinguished name.

`CORP\\desktop_user_xxxxx` is not really a distinguished name. It is simply `DOMAIN\sAMAccountName`.

Since the `ldapsearch` client you are using permits it for binding to AD you can use that to retrieve the users true `dn`.

```
ldapsearch  -b "dc=corp,dc=xxxxxx,dc=co,dc=xx" \
 -D "CORP\\desktop_user_xxxxx" \
 -H "ldap://corp.xxxxxx.co.xx" \
 -w Pxxxxxxxx  \
 "(&(objectClass=Person)(sAMAccountName=desktop_user_xxxxx))"
```

The above should yield the user's entry you are seeking and the first line should start with `dn:`. It will look something like this...

```
dn: CN=Desktop User xxxxx,ou=Users,dc=corp,dc=xxxxxx,dc=co,dc=xx
```

Use the entire string after `dn:` as the `binddn` attribute in your nginx config.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work out for me. I still doubt the URL to be the problem. 
url ldap://corp.xxxx.co.xx/DC=corp,DC=xxxxx,DC=co,DC=xx?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=person);

Comment: Found the solution. The error was in the URL itself. The port number 3268 worked instead of 389. Although I am not sure why it so happened.